# In Daniel Bernstein's implementation of NIST P-224 elliptic curves, what is the encoding used by the secret e?

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm working with https://cr.yp.to/nistp224/library.html and trying to correctly format my integer e for the library. The doc states:

> The integer e is 2^224 + 2^216(e[0] - 136) + 2^208(e[1] - 136) + ... +
> 2^0(e[27] - 136).

I already have an integer e in mind, but I've got it encoded as a big endian array of bytes. What is the encoding above called (if it has a name)? Is there a known method for taking an integer and encoding it in the above format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the encoding above called (if it has a name)?

I don't expect so - it appears that Dan specified this specifically for P224.  The addition of $2^{224}$ is to prevent someone from being tempted to optimize the point multiplication routine by skipping leading ones (although it doesn't do a perfect job; bit 224 may be a one or a zero based on what `e[0]` is, because of the subtraction of 136).  I do not know why he specified subtracting 136 from each byte - the only immediately obvious reason for doing something like that would be to avoid accidentally running into a multiple of the order of the curve, and this doesn't do that (although, as Dan mentions on his page, the probability of doing that is fantastically small).

> Is there a known method for taking an integer and encoding it in the above format?

It can easily be done with a two-step process:

- Take your string of 28 bytes (in bigendian format) and convert it into an integer
- Add the constant 0x77777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777778

which is $2^{224} - 136 \cdot (2^{216} + 2^{208} + ... + 2^8 + 2^0)$, this will add in the $2^{224}$ and effectively subtract 136 from each byte).

Comment: 136 = 0x88, so I assume that the value has something to do with the [implementation](https://cr.yp.to/talks/2001.11.02/slides-djb-20011102-nistp224-a4.pdf#page=23) treating each 4-bit chunk of the scalar as a value in $[-8,\dots,7]$.